# iOS 7.1 BLE peripherial advertisment issue

Tags: ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral

I wrote an application with is advertising and scanning in the same time. It is working well, but I have an issue. After some time mz peripherial stop advertising.

I tried to restart but my phone and application it still not working.

Here is the peripheral implementation:

```
@implementation PeripheralManager

+ (PeripheralManager*)sharedInstance
{
    static PeripheralManager *_sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[PeripheralManager alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}

-(id)initWithUUID:(NSString *)UUID{

    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.UUID = UUID;
        self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

    }
    return self;
}
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {
    if (peripheral.state != CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {



        self.transferCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];

        CBMutableService *transferService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:self.UUID] primary:YES];

        transferService.characteristics = @[_transferCharacteristic];

        [_peripheralManager addService:transferService];


    }
}
-(void)startAdvertisment{
    [_peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:self.UUID]], CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: PERIPHERAL_NAME}];


}
```

Comment: If you wrote an application, you should ship the important piece of code

Comment: Thank you! I edited the post with the code.